# Smooth Scroll Jumps Rather than Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have used Smooth Scroll Plugin From CSS TRICKS,
Its working great but for only 2 ancoher links and not for another one, please see the demo here,

**[LIVE DEMO](http://www.repsly.com/homepage-2014?hs_preview=SWdrUZhj-1153692371)**

Its working Great for industries and Pricing, but on testimonial its just jump to the position and also the fixed nav cut off the section too.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('a[href^="#"]').on('click', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = this.hash,
            $target = $(target);
        $('html, body').stop().animate({
            'scrollTop': $target.offset().top - 130 // - 130px (nav-height)
        }, 900, 'swing', function () {
            // Replace this with something that can be easily parsed and used by your code
            window.location.hash = '3' + target;
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here i've made a jsfiddle,
jsfiddle.net/Thq62/

and it's working fine just added a proper id and hash to the links

Comment: Added the perfect Id and hash to the link, but still not working